# ¿Cómo poder obtener los valores del count?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es un examen en php y me sale este error, el código esta así:

```
$totp="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `detalle_resultados` WHERE `ID_RESULTADO`='$quiz'";
$resultp = $conn->query($totp);
$tota="SELECT count(*) FROM 'detalle_resultados'  WHERE `ID_RESULTADO`='$quiz' AND `RESPUESTA`=1";
$resulta = $conn->query($tota);
$calif=($resulta*100)/$resultp ;
echo $calif;
```

Lo que yo quiero es poder realizar la operación para que me la imprima posteriormente.

Comment: Basicamente el error esta aquí: `$calif=($tota*100)/$totp;` ya que las variables `$tota` y `$totp` son un string no un numero.

Comment: ya le modifique es parte y ahora me sale esto Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to number in C:\xampp\htdocs\DECO\Competencias\Cactualiza.php on line 38

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Y ese error no tiene nada que ver con tu codigo, sobre todo si arreglaste los anteriores.

Comment: Por lo que puedo ver en tu código te falta hacer un **fetch** al resultado del  query para que así puedes obtener el valor,  calcular la calificación.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera `$row = resulta->fetch_assoc();` y traes las filas que te dio la consulta y se convierte en un arreglo, en el sql puedes poner al lado del `count(*)` un apodo para que identifiques que así se va a llamar la posición en el arreglo, algo así `count(*) as conteo`, y el arreglo sería `$row[0]["conteo"]`

Answer (score 3):

El problema que tienes es que estás tratando de hacer una operación matemática con variables que no son números, las variables `$tota` y `$totp` son string no númericos, por lo que PHP no puede realizar las operaciones que intentas.

A parte de lo indicado, también debes recuperar los datos después de la consulta, para ello puedes utilizar `PDO::fetch()` si utilizas PDO o `mysqli_result::fetch_array` ([o alguno de los metodos destinado a ello](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php)) si utilizas MySQLi.

Debes segir los siguientes pasos:

1. Crear la consulta
2. Ejecutar la consulta
3. Recuperar los datos de la consulta
4. Trabajar con los datos

Ejemplo con MySQLi como es tu caso:

```
<?php

// cremos la consulta añadimos un alias a count(*)
$totp="SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM `detalle_resultados` WHERE `ID_RESULTADO`='$quiz'";
// ejecutamos la consulta
if (!$result = $conn->query($totp)) {printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error); exit;}
// recuperamos el resultado
$total = $result->fetch_assoc()['total'];

// cremos la consulta añadimos un alias a count(*)
$tota ="SELECT count(*) total FROM 'detalle_resultados'  WHERE `ID_RESULTADO`='$quiz' AND `RESPUESTA`=1";
// ejecutamos la consulta
if (!$result = $conn->query($tota)) {printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error); exit;}
// recuperamos el resultado
$totalAcertado = $result->fetch_assoc()['total'];


// realizamos la operacion
$calif = ($totalAcertado * 100) / $total;

// mostramos el resultado
echo $calif;
```

Documentacion:

- [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)
- [mysqli_result::fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

---

Ejemplo con sentencias preparadas MySQLi:

```
/* crear una sentencia preparada */
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM detalle_resultados WHERE ID_RESULTADO = ?')) {

    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $quiz);

    /* ejecutar la consulta */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* ligar variables de resultado */
    $stmt->bind_result($total);

    /* obtener valor */
    $stmt->fetch();
} else {
    printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error); exit;
}

/* crear una sentencia preparada */
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT count(*) total FROM detalle_resultados  WHERE ID_RESULTADO= ? AND RESPUESTA = 1')) {

    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $quiz);

    /* ejecutar la consulta */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* ligar variables de resultado */
    $stmt->bind_result($totalAcertado);

    /* obtener valor */
    $stmt->fetch();
} else {
    printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error); exit;
}

// realizamos la operación
$calificacion = ($totalAcertado * 100) / $total;

// mostramos el resultado
echo $calificacion;
```

Documentación:

- [mysqli::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)

---

Ejemplo, en Caso de utilizar PDO:

```
<?php

// cremos la consulta añadimos un alias a count(*)
$totp="SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM `detalle_resultados` WHERE `ID_RESULTADO`='$quiz'";
// ejecutamos la consulta
$result = $conn->query($totp);
// recuperamos el resultado
$total = $result->fetch()['total'];

// cremos la consulta añadimos un alias a count(*)
$tota ="SELECT count(*) total FROM 'detalle_resultados'  WHERE `ID_RESULTADO`='$quiz' AND `RESPUESTA`=1";
// ejecutamos la consulta
$result = $conn->query($tota);
// recuperamos el resultado
$totalAcertado = $result->fetch()['total'];


// realizamos la operacion
$calif = ($totalAcertado * 100) / $total;

// mostramos el resultado
echo $calif;
```

Documentación:

- [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php)
- [PDO:fech()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)

---

> Como nota indicar que algunos de estos códigos son **vulnerables a Inyección SQL**.

Comment: si lo ejecuto con mysqli me sale el siguiente error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\DECO\Competencias\Cactualiza.php:46 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Comment: @user147258 Te he editado nuevamente la respuesta, cambia las lineas: `$result = $conn->query($totp);` por: `if (!$result = $conn->query($totp)) {printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error);}` y lo mismo con la de `$tota`. Pruebalo y dinos que te sale

Comment: Perdona que te dé tanto la lata Xerif. Sería mejor usar un método más específico, por ejemplo `fetch_assoc`, porque `fetch_array()` trae los datos dos veces, como array asociativo y como array numérico. Yo haría algo así: `$mData=$result->fetch_assoc(); $total=$mData["total"];` La comprobación de errores tampoco está bien, pues el código sigue buscando datos aunque ocurra un error, debería ponerse todo dentro de un `if ( condicion ) {  //si hay error } else { //si no hay error busca los datos }`

Comment: @A.Cedano No te preocupes, agradezco el apunte y estoy deacuerdo con tigo. Ya esta editada, aun que vamos a volver loco al OP. Un saludo.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo probé como me comentas y me imprime el siguiente error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\DECO\Competencias\Cactualiza.php:39 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\DECO\Competencias\Cactualiza.php on line 39

Comment: @user147258 El error ya lo tienes en alguna de las consultas ya que el query te esta retornando un boleano. Aplica el código tras mi ultima edición con las recomendaciones de A. Cedano y dinos que error te da la consulta para poder avanzar en el problema.

Comment: me sale Error: Unknown column '5db9b9b7d23df' in 'where clause'

Comment: ¿Tienes constantes definidas? Parece que está confundiendo `ID_RESULTADO` o `RESPUESTA` con el valor de una constante establecido a `5db9b9b7d23df`

Comment: @user147258 Como indica A. Cedano, debe de estar expandiendo el nombre de las columnas como si fuese una CONSTANTE. Te edito la pregunta una vez mas y te expongo un ejemplo con sentencias preparadas para evitar esto y otros errores, fijate que he utilizado comillas simples `'`.